# mongoexport giving error: could not connect to localhost

Tags: windows, mongodb

I'm keep getting this error when calling mongoexport.

[image]

I'm wondering if it is because mongodb is not running locally. I'm very new to mongodb, so if it's the case I'm wondering how to check if mongodb is running on Windows. If it is not the reason, what could it be? 
Thanks.

Comment: Well, _is_ Mongo running on your machine?

Comment: I personally dont use mongo, so im not sure how to check if mongo is running. I tried looking into services.msc and could not find mongo service in there. Does this mean that mongo is not running? if so, how can I start it? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make sure that mongod is running on your system.  Mongo is not set up as a service by default.

In the directory you are in above.  You need to type the command mongod  <-- not mongodb....  to start the mongo database server.   This is assuming you have a data directory set up.. by default mongo will use \data\db  but you can specify if  you would like

```
C:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe --dbpath d:\test\mongodb\data
```

If you want to set it up as a service, you can find that here : 
https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/

Finally, what are you trying to export?  You are specifying a collection in the code above.   You usually call it like this.

```
mongoexport --db test --collection traffic --out traffic.json
```

assuming of course you have a collection called traffic.